# Function object vs. function in a header-only library

Tags: c++11

I am writing a library that I would like to keep header-only. In the code I have something like this:

```
// Wrapper.h
#ifndef INCLUDED_WRAPPER_H
#define INCLUDED_WRAPPER_H

namespace quux {

template <typename T, typename U>
class Wrapper
{
  T m_t;
  U m_u;
public:
  Wrapper(T const & t, U const & u) : m_t(t), m_u(u) { }

  // ...
};

} // namespace quux

#endif // INCLUDED_WRAPPER_H

// Foo.h
#ifndef INCLUDED_FOO_H
#define INCLUDED_FOO_H

#include <type_traits>

#include "Wrapper.h"

namespace quux {

// if some type is special, then there will be a specialization of this
// struct derived from std::true_type
template <typename T> struct is_special : std::false_type { };

class Foo
{
  template <typename T>
  Wrapper<Foo, T> impl(T const & t, std::true_type ) const
  {
    return Wrapper<Foo, T>(*this, t);
  }

  template <typename T>
  T const & impl(T const & t, std::false_type ) const;
  {
    return t;
  }
public:

  template <typename T>
  auto operator()(T const & t) const // using automatic return type deduction
  {
    return impl(t, is_special<T>());
  }

};

#if 1
Foo const foo;
#else
template <typename T>
auto foo(T const & t) // using automatic return type deduction
{
  return Foo()(t);
}
#endif

} // namespace quux

#endif // INCLUDED_FOO_H
```

I see two different ways to have a callable entity with the name "quux::foo": a constant object named foo (the #if 1 - branch) or a function named foo that forwards its arguments to a Foo-object (the #else-branch). Which version should I prefer? A const Object has internal linkage so there are no linker errors if the header is included in multiple translation units. Are there any salient differences between the two approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are calling a function, and your function object has no state, I would go with the function interface.

First, because functions can be overloaded, while function objects cannot outside of the body of the function object.  You may wish to enable ADL extensions to your function.

Second because function objects are wierd.  They cannot be converted to function pointers (in your case for no good reason), for example (note you can fix that with more boilerplate).  Weird solutions are only a good idea when simple solutions are insufficient: in this case the simple perfect forwarding function is simpler.

Finally you might want to make your functions perfect forward, and have `T&&` rvalues give functions that return `T` at the outermost API level.  This enables lifetime extension of temporaries to pass through your functions.